# Lein repl-options :init

Tags: clojure

According to https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj 
I can attach a :init inside of a :repl-options.

However, when I try:

```
lein version; echo "====="; cat project.clj; echo "====="; lein repl
```

I get the output:

```
Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_29 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
=====
(defproject
  test "0.0.1"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :jvm-opts ["-Xms4g"  "-Xmx4g"]
  :repl-options {
                 :init (println "Init")
                 }
  )

=====
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: [:init (println "Init")] (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: [:init (println "Init")]
    at clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.createWithCheck(PersistentHashMap.java:89)
    at clojure.core$hash_map.doInvoke(core.clj:327)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
    at leiningen.repl$repl_options.invoke(repl.clj:16)
    at leiningen.repl$repl_server.doInvoke(repl.clj:69)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:146)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:546)
    at leiningen.repl$repl.invoke(repl.clj:145)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:262)
    at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:329)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:332)
    at user$eval47.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
    ... 16 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

In particular, I don't understand why [:init +func+] is treated as the key, rather than :init treated as the key.

Thanks!

Comment: @dsouth: I'm an idiot. I didn't realize the first result on google linked to master rather than stable. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Everyone's an idiot most of the time. It takes a smart person to realize it and admit it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but the link you gave points to master, which is probably Leiningen 2 and not the same as the stable branch, which is probably 1.7-ish? If you switch the branch to stable on your github link, there is no :init parameter...